# How to structure my states and routing in ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router

I´m building a e-commerce site using angular1 and ui-router (1.0.0.beta3).

But I´m not sure how to setup this up.
This is what I have in mind.

```
const home = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/',
    views: {
        header: 'header',
        navbar: 'navbar',
        sidenav: 'sideNav',
        content: 'home'
    }
};

const category = {
    name: 'home.category',
    url: '/{url}',
    views: {
        content: 'categoryPage'
    }
};

const product = {
    name: 'home.category.product',
    url: '/{url}',
    views: {
        content: 'productPage'
    }
};
```

we can´t control links that come from the cms it self, "/about-us" and "/category-x" can be a category or a cms-page so we added a route state where we can resolve the entity_type (product, category or cms-page)

```
    .state('home.router', {
        url: '/{url}?:{page:int}&:{limit:int}&:id',
        params: {
            limit: null,
            category: null,
            page: {
                dynamic: true
            },
            id: {
                dynamic: true
            }
        },
        templateProvider: ['urlRewrite', function(urlRewrite) {
            switch (urlRewrite.entity_type) {
                case 'category':
                    return '<category-page limit="$stateParams.limit" page="$stateParams.page" category="{name: $resolve.urlRewrite.request_path, id: $resolve.urlRewrite.entity_id}"/>';
                case 'product':
                    return '<product-page id="$resolve.urlRewrite.entity_id"/>';
                case 'cms-page':
                default:
                    return '<page url="$resolve.urlRewrite.target_path" />';
            }
        }],
        resolve: {
            urlRewrite: ['UrlRewrite', '$stateParams', function(UrlRewrite, $stateParams) {
                return UrlRewrite.getUrlRewrite($stateParams.url);
            }]
        }
    });
```

the problem is that category and route url patterns collide.
and we can´t really use parent/child inherits etc etc..

How should we go about resolving "unknown" urls?

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gXzDO5j3arP8QCrpwL9k?p=preview

Comment: so the problem is the home.router can catch category urls which you do not want? Is there no way of distinguishing the real category urls from the links from the cms? (e.g. by changing the format of urls caught)

Comment: Spot on the problem.. and no we cant change the url structure. So the url "/hey-yo" could be a category or a cms-page :(

Comment: I might still be misunderstanding. You do enter category/product links without them coming from the cms site? And I assume you control those. Can you not change their pattern as to not clash?

Comment: I could have urls like /c/ for categories but that is not very nice urls. Surly there must be a clever way to eg use the $urlMatcherFactoryProvider somehow?

Comment: unfortunately I am not familiar with this. Maybe there is something in the docs [here](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/url.urlmatcherfactory.html#constructor). Good luck

Comment: Been trying to figure it out by looking at the docs but no luck yet.. will keep trying.. thx for your time!  :)

Comment: I have checked your Plunker link and couldn't understand your problem exactly. What is your expected result in plunker?

Comment: Both links loads category state, expected is that they load different state

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide you with the sample snippet. It will give you the idea.

```
appName.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider' ,function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
        var state = $injector.get('$state');
        var $localStorage = $injector.get('$localStorage');
        if($localStorage.user){
            return '/dashboard'
        }else {
            return '/login'
        }
    });
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateProvider: function ($templateFactory, $localStorage) {
                    return $templateFactory.fromUrl(asset_path('angular/templates/base/login.html'));
                },
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('Interceptor');

}]);
```